# Display an overdue task on task list

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

I currently have a task list (displayed below) that I want to convey a way to represent that it is overdue. I don't want to add too many icons such as warnings etc, so I figured the best way may be to highlight the date in red, and when you hover over the date a tooltip displays that states "This task is overdue!".

Was wondering what may be a better way to show this state. Perhaps also include the task-state icon to be red?

[image]

Comment: As noted, however, I like your overall design! Will all the various icon states you have now be clearly understood by the user?

Comment: @Mattynabib I do have a tooltip hover for those who aren't familiar, but the icon states should be fairly linear in regards to their actions etc :)

Comment: @BryceSnyder This is a web-app, right? I like the clean look but how long before touchscreens detect my finger hovering for more information? I am concerned about the clarity of the icons on the left-hand side as I have never seen them used before, anywhere. Anyways as far as the overdue issue is concerned, I would opt for an overdue tag placed to the right of the date.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus if you can find material icons that are better suited for the representation of each state, by all means lol

Comment: My sincere apologies if my statement sounded ill-willed but I would like to know what the pie, the clock, the winner's circle, and the pause icons represent in the context of your app.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98043/tasks-state-colors-with-icons haha, I was being sincere! I literally can't find anything within the material icons that seem to relate to anything task based :(

Comment: @BryceSnyder I'll have to give this more thought later and possibly come up with a suggestion using my MS Paint-fu skills, lol

Comment: [MS Paint-fu incoming!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pSsJG.jpg). You can style this to your liking but I vouch for getting rid of ambiguous icons altogether and implementing a tag-ish system and allow the user to sort and/or filter

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I had never thought of adding a tag system to it, I like that. I'll have to play with it and see what I can manage to get to work for the product!

Comment: @BryceSnyder Let me know how it goes and if you like it enough then I can make an answer out of it :-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus As someone who has never seen this before, coming in from nowhere, my guess for what the symbols mean is (top down): task in progress, task not started, task completed, task started then paused. I don't know if that matches what they actually mean, or how generalizable my experience is, but I don't think OP needs to worry too much about changing them.

Comment: @Benubird My guesses would have been in-progress, waiting, done, paused. I still think it's important for OP to remove the ambiguity though. Another thought I have would be to make those icons actionable so that when the user presses the icon then a pull-out menu shows up with all of the symbols and their meanings listed so that the user can change statuses quickly. Sometimes it's difficult to pull yourself out of your comfort zone and think like a user.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have already implemented that functionality as well. It's easy to think like a user!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Maybe you should think about the sorting first.

**Overdue tasks shown first**

If items overdue are fairly detrimental, those should potentially be grouped first on the top of the listing, maybe apply a grouping that will catch the user's eye. Currently, you might have a red date label, but what if the overdue item was thrown below the fold? Even worse, what if it was hidden under pages? Bringing them up will make it more noticeable and give a sense of urgency needed for something as critical.

**Consider how you display due dates**

Dates are hard to remember, people don't normally remember what day of the month it is, and to add more urgency, you might want to consider changing dates to "5 days left." For tasks that are overdue, might consider just showing "overdue" unless there is a strict policy on if a certain task is overdue a certain amount of days, then maybe tie days to that task.

Comment: The sort order is not a bad idea either. In fact, perhaps you could have a third category in your top bar that is just Overdue Tasks.

Comment: Good answer. I would also point out that color should not be the only indicator that something is to be noted.

Comment: @EricStoltz very valid point. Urgency can be created by hierarchy, color, font choices and even how information is presented.

Comment: My image doesn't display the search functionality that is implemented. It allows the user to refine the search by hidden, overdue etc. This is a part of a SaaS being used for insurance companies; they are very strict on using specific date formats, otherwise, I would use that short-hand for sure!

Comment: @BryceSnyder that's very important information right there. Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Majo0od haha sorry, I  did leave that out! I'm so used to "components", so it cuts my questions down to the minor things...

Comment: @BryceSnyder oh no biggie. After all, you know the product best!

Comment: I agree 100% with "Overdue tasks shown first", but why limit it to overdue tasks? Sort all (unfinished) tasks by "earliest deadline first" in the default view, and the overdue tasks will be at the top "for free".

Answer (score 25):

Sorting or special text denotations are fine, but it isn't very easy for users to tell the difference at a quick glance.  I think **highlighting** the overdue item would make it pop out the strongest:

[image: Highlight the overdue items in the task list]

The highlighting shouldn't be too drastic, even what I did here might be too much (I used #fff5f5).  It should just be enough for the user to be able to quickly and easily distinguish the items.

Comment: Like it, but maybe highlight it in a light red instead of grey... The grey looks more like a hover effect

Comment: @cullub Example edited.  Good suggestion!

Answer (score 8):

You may add a red rectangle next to the date. The size of the rectangle will vary according to the days overdue.

[image]

Comment: Bars like that usually indicate progress for me, and what happens if it's 100 days over due? does it span all the way to the end?

Comment: @Majo0od You have a point, it will be difficult for users to understand the meaning the first time. But once the users understand it, it will be very easy to use. They will be able to identify overdues and big overdues in one glance. If it is more than a 100 days you may add a symbol at the end of the bar i.e. three dots .

Comment: I don't think the bar really works.  It's confusing, and there is no frame of reference to indicate what a particular bar size means.  Why not a bold red message that says "X days overdue!"?

Comment: In my humble opinion accuracy is not an issue in this case. The user needs to identify tasks with small overdue, midium overdue, big overdue and very big overdue. Also, the screen has a lot of text and adding a text message will overload the screen.

Comment: If the bars had black text overlaying them indicating the amount overdue then it'll be self-explanatory.  I hope users will notice that majorly over due items will have longer red bars.  You'll need to test out some extreme values though, and cap it in case someone uses this like they use e-mail (30 thousand unread messages?  I have friends like that).

Answer (score 6):

This looks very good - why not just append the word "OVERDUE" in red to the date when you make it red? No need to make the user take an extra action just to know the status, you seem to have room on the date line. Then when they click the date it could take them straight to the situation that needs rectifying.

Comment: I had thought about that as well, but I wasn't sure if I were making things too "Wordy" in a sense? The previous design seemed to have a lot of misused icons in said areas that had a hover to them which stated what was wrong; so I completely understand what you mean by not making them take another action...

Comment: Yeah... I think if you can show a status in place, show it. You have room, and I think if making it a bit more wordy makes it pop out more, so much the better: there's an action needed! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Building on [DesignerAnalysy's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/98093/57088) you could use bars to show days/time left as well as overdue (my access to graphics tools is limited, but the following should give an idea):

[image: progress bars]

Depending on the range of how far ahead tasks are planned you might only show these bars in, say, the week leading up to that task's deadline (in which case the bounding box would always represent 7 days, and you *may* not need explicit statement of the time left/overdue).  If the box represented a month, you may want `(6d)` or `(6 days)` after the bars.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to (or instead of) highlighting the entire overdue item as @Chase Sandman suggested, you could also highlight the date alone, by displaying it using white (or some other light) text on a stark red background. This will make it clear why the highlighting has been done (that it relates to the date) while also making it visually easy to notice.

And on hovering, you could display some text near the date such as "Overdue by N days" - making it actual on-page dynamic text makes it easier to read, without the transience problem of tooltips.

Comment: Pretty much if they are overdue the ship sinks, so they really don't want to get to that state because they are in fire-fighting mode then... I definitely think there needs to be more prominence added to the UX, I just can't decide how I want it to lead up to it yet... the filling bars don't do justice for me.