# Best way to represent a "go to" action?

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

I'm trying to **determine how to represent the state of an action that navigates** the user to *another page*.

Currently, **the action is present by a hover event on the text field**, which I find isn't too intuitive and the default behaviour.

Trying to **determine how to better display this in an intuitive matter** but with my current real-estate, I find there are not many ways to convey this.

**Note:** This is typically displayed in a table-like format with multiple rows and other actionable states on the cards. **Having the ability to click the whole card does not work in the full context!**

*This is what I have for the display:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's already more than one convention for that: when you hover over active text, it lights up.  Click it and you go somewhere (or, more precisely, "somewhere" comes to you).

Generally, unless there's some real reason that a convention *will not* work in your situation, you should follow the convention.  The basic principle is:  eliminate surprises.

Answer (score 1):

MMacD has already nailed it, i think, by suggesting you stick with conventions.

Because i cannot add a comment to his post, i'll simply add my additions as an answer:  Assuming standard conventions work (hover-over links will change their color), you can emphasize interactivity with some other CSS tricks.

For example, instead of just including a static arrow icon -> you can instead transition it in, or make it bounce to the right side when someone hovers over the text.  You can do the same with a PDF icon to help emphasize the file type it is: on hover-over, fade-in or add drop shadow to the icon.

If you dont think the hover-over text effects are effective enough, you can add additional effects for that interaction: add a drop shadow to link text, add an underline to text, make it fade/transition into another text color...

It seems to me the pickle you are in is not to find a new interactive convention, but simply polish a standard interaction scheme.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple icon as a hint

Use a persistently visible icon to indicate the expected action.

[image: Design with right arrow next to title indicating link]

I'm assuming that your users are fully aware that the object is a file and that files are the only type of object being linked to. If that is not the case, I would also provide some kind of icon or label indicating that it's a `file` or the type of file.

[image: File link with file type icon]

*Update in response to the OP's comment ...*

### When in doubt, make it obvious

If you want to make the action as clear as possible, just spell it out and create the appearance of a button.

[image: File link provided as a distinct button]

Note that the button doesn't necessarily *need* to be the only target area. If the whole card is the target, make sure the button lights up in some way to indicate the function.

Comment: I've attempted to use an icon like that and didn't feel it worked in the context. And yes, this is a task that they will work against on a file they are directed to. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98084/display-an-overdue-task-on-task-list

Comment: ^ See my update for a more self-apparent solution.

Comment: Sorry, file in this context is actually another web page specifically. They files are not actual "file context" more so something the system has documented/created. -- Edited to reflect this.

Comment: How does that change anything (other than the file icon)? The user is still "opening" a record.